# Is it possible to automate changing some security settings in Catalina?

Tags: macos, security, automation, preferences, mdm

I realize the user would have to enter their password, but beyond that step could the process of adding a program to Accessibility, Full Disk Access and Screen Recording be automated in some way? Programs like [Teamviewer](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/44699-how-to-control-a-mac-running-macos-10-14-or-higher) and [Splashtop](https://support-splashtopbusiness.splashtop.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035055131-MacOS-10-15-Catalina-11-Big-Sur-additional-Security-and-Privacy-requirements-for-Mac-Streamer-and-Mac-Business-App) (to name two that I know of personally), require the user to make these changes before I can provide remote support. This is a bit much to ask of people for whom minimizing a window is a challenge.

BTW, the Macs in this situation are not part of an organization; they are individually owned Macs that could be anywhere in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set up a MDM and you can easily make configuration profiles so your peers or people you support don’t have to manage their Macs as much.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/welcome/web
- https://www.apple.com/macos/server/
- https://www.fleetsmith.com/ or https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/

Comment: Thank you for replying, bmike. My impression about MDM is that it is for organizations to manage devices used by their employees or students, requiring enrollment in a service, etc.  Because of your answer I modified my question to clarify.

Comment: I know parents that use MDM for one child and two adults. My answer still fits exactly what you want without any effort of learning to roll your own scripts @user428697 excellent edit to clarify the “ask”. I chose JAMF now since it’s free for small groups and designed for people that don’t do IT as their job.

Comment: Reading about MDM, JAMF, Fleetsmith, iMazing, Jumpcloud, Apple Business/Ed Mgr, Apple Configurator 2, etc., etc at 3am left me feeling OMG, this is daunting as heck. I can figure out pretty much anything but in this case I wondered if it's worth it. Your reply suggests it is. I'll poke around looking for a tutorial related to an ultra-simple scenario like using JAMF for a family or individual user.  Would I need to create JAMF accounts for each client who has one or more Macs?

Comment: It’s pretty easy, why not sign up for one and spend 20 minutes setting up JAMF now? You’ll know what’s up quickly enough. It used to take me days to get small teams trained up for the old way of management. Now it’s half day session split across 2 hour chunks with MDM. Less reading, more doing is my advice.

Answer (score 1):

Brandon with JumpCloud here — if you're considering a small scale MDM deployment, JumpCloud is free for up to 10 users and 10 systems. We offer a policy to enable those screen recording permissions on Big Sur systems, detailed at https://jumpcloud.com/blog/macos-big-sur-screen-recording-policy. You can check us out at either https://www.jumpcloud.com/demo or https://console.jumpcloud.com/signup. We have a free education program at https://jumpcloud.com/university, and we have a free Slack workspace for our admins at https://join.slack.com/t/jumpcloudlounge/shared_invite/zt-esobabj4-Ytqy4ZSTo6ZONoALoGHAKA. Let me know if I can help with questions.